# Search a column to see if new data exist and proceed from there

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

New to Apps Script and want to write a simple function to test the waters. Unfortunately, I am having some difficulties. I want the function to check column E and see if there is existing data. If yes, I want it to add a formula to the column next to it. Else do nothing and check the next row. When running the code listed below I get a Error:

> Exception: The starting row of the range is too small.

Could somebody please point out what exactly I am doing wrong?

```
function dateToColumn() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dbGoogleSheet);
  Logger.log('Google Sheet database used' + ' ' + ss.getName());
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1')
  Logger.log(dataSheet.getName());
  var rangeData = dataSheet.getDataRange();
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 5, lastRow - 1, lastColumn - 1);


  if (dataSheet.getName() === "Form Responses 1") {
    var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
    //Logger.log(rangeValues)
    for (i = 0; i < lastColumn - 1; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < lastRow - 1; j++) {
        // Logger.log(dataSheet.getRange(j,i));
        if (rangeValues[j][i] !== null) {
          dataSheet.getRange(j, i++).setFormula(`=YEAR(` + j, i + `)`);
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    return;
  }
};
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't put any formulas on the Form Response Sheet.  Also is there any reason why your not using onFormSubmit trigger to access the data when there is a submission and then you can use either e.namedValues or e.values where e is the event object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `j` is been initialized as `0` and it's being used in a `getRange`. The minimal value is 1.

Please bear in mind that Arrays uses 0 based indexes while getRange and other SpreadsheetApp methods use 1 based "indexes".

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the point mentioned in the other answer, you should also be aware of the `i` index.

Moreover, you are passing a wrong parameter to the `setFormula` method. So depending on *how* exactly you want to use the `YEAR` formula, you should reformat it accordingly.

Therefore, you should be changing this line:

```
dataSheet.getRange(j, i++).setFormula(`=YEAR(` + j, i + `)`);
```

To:

```
dataSheet.getRange(j+1, i+2).setFormula('=YEAR(' + (j, i) + ')');
```

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column);
- [YEAR formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093061).